# How to make entire box in dropdown menu (menuitem) clickable instead of just the text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a menu bar with different items, with sub items,

```
 //ASCX FILE

<asp:MenuItem Text="Item" Value="Item" Selectable="false">
  <asp:MenuItem Text="SubItemA" Value="SubitemA" NavigateUrl="dsklfsl.com"
  </asp:MenuItem>
  <asp:MenuItem Text="SubItemB" Value="SubitemB" NavigateUrl="ghhffssl.com"
  </asp:MenuItem>
</asp>
```

The problem is that if I hover over Item, then SubItemA, I am only able to click when I am hovering over exactly the text "SubItemA", is there a way to set it so that if I hover anywhere in the box containing the text "SubItemA", I will be able to click there as well?

I have looked through the different properties for MenuItems but I haven't been able to find anything , its possible I missed something thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1279816&page=3). Basically you need to modify the CSS of the menu item content.

Comment: This works in the case when I have static menuitems. I also found that if you want to solve the problem for dynamic menuitems then you need to use CSS styling on the DynamicMenuItemStyle Tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can "upgrade" it with the **[CSS-friendly control adapter](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/menu.aspx)**.

It generates a list instead of a table and expands the anchor tag inside the menuitem to be fully hoverable

Answer (score 0):

Use `<StaticItemTemplate>` or `<DynamicItemTemplate>` of Menu to display your menu items. this would make entire block region clickable.

http://books.google.com/books?id=KzsUd3ohSJkC&pg=PA446&lpg=PA446&dq=%3CStaticItemTemplate%3E+of+menu+C%23&source=bl&ots=Ay3awQuGMO&sig=5Zy3ohxbCDhJNj6LEeqdgfvxZlY&hl=en&ei=aw63Tcm5NIq-tge_zZyjAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%3CStaticItemTemplate%3E%20of%20menu%20C%23&f=false

http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Components/MenutemplateC.htm